# node.js app failing when trying to create

Tags: node.js, openshift

I'm getting the following error when trying to create a node.js app:

> The initial build for the application failed: Shell command
>   '/sbin/runuser -s /bin/sh 573d0ed67628e174130000dc -c "exec
>   /usr/bin/runcon 'unconfined_u:system_r:openshift_t:s0:c3,c846' /bin/sh
>   -c \"gear postreceive --init >> /tmp/initial-build.log 2>&1\""' returned an error. rc=255 .Last 10 kB of build output: Stopping NodeJS
>   cartridge Repairing links for 1 deployments Building git ref 'master',
>   commit 93e0126 Building NodeJS cartridge npm info it worked if it ends
>   with ok npm info using npm@1.4.28 npm info using node@v0.10.35 npm
>   info preinstall node-js-getting-started@0.1.2 npm info trying registry
>   request attempt 1 at 20:55:41 npm http GET
>   https://registry.npmjs.org/director npm info trying registry request
>   attempt 1 at 20:55:41 npm http GET
>   https://registry.npmjs.org/cool-ascii-faces npm http 200
>   https://registry.npmjs.org/cool-ascii-faces npm info retry fetch
>   attempt 1 at 20:55:41 npm http GET
>   https://registry.npmjs.org/cool-ascii-faces/-/cool-ascii-faces-1.3.4.tgz
>   npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/director npm info retry fetch
>   attempt 1 at 20:55:41 npm http GET
>   https://registry.npmjs.org/director/-/director-1.2.8.tgz npm http 200
>   https://registry.npmjs.org/cool-ascii-faces/-/cool-ascii-faces-1.3.4.tgz
>   npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/director/-/director-1.2.8.tgz
>   npm info install cool-ascii-faces@1.3.4 into
>   /var/lib/openshift/573d0ed67628e174130000dc/app-root/runtime/repo npm
>   info install director@1.2.8 into
>   /var/lib/openshift/573d0ed67628e174130000dc/app-root/runtime/repo npm
>   info installOne cool-ascii-faces@1.3.4 npm info installOne
>   director@1.2.8 npm info preinstall cool-ascii-faces@1.3.4 npm info
>   trying registry request attempt 1 at 20:55:41 npm http GET
>   https://registry.npmjs.org/stream-spigot npm http 200
>   https://registry.npmjs.org/stream-spigot npm info retry fetch attempt
>   1 at 20:55:41 npm http GET
>   https://registry.npmjs.org/stream-spigot/-/stream-spigot-3.0.5.tgz npm
>   info preinstall director@1.2.8 npm info build
>   /var/lib/openshift/573d0ed67628e174130000dc/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/director
>   npm info linkStuff director@1.2.8 npm info install director@1.2.8 npm
>   info postinstall director@1.2.8 npm http 200
>   https://registry.npmjs.org/stream-spigot/-/stream-spigot-3.0.5.tgz npm
>   info install stream-spigot@3.0.5 into
>   /var/lib/openshift/573d0ed67628e174130000dc/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/cool-ascii-faces
>   npm info installOne stream-spigot@3.0.5 npm info preinstall
>   stream-spigot@3.0.5 npm info trying registry request attempt 1 at
>   20:55:42 npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/readable-stream npm
>   info trying registry request attempt 1 at 20:55:42 npm http GET
>   https://registry.npmjs.org/xtend npm http 200
>   https://registry.npmjs.org/xtend npm http 200
>   https://registry.npmjs.org/readable-stream npm info retry fetch
>   attempt 1 at 20:55:42 npm http GET
>   https://registry.npmjs.org/xtend/-/xtend-4.0.1.tgz npm info retry
>   fetch attempt 1 at 20:55:42 npm http GET
>   https://registry.npmjs.org/readable-stream/-/readable-stream-1.1.14.tgz
>   npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/xtend/-/xtend-4.0.1.tgz npm
>   http 200
>   https://registry.npmjs.org/readable-stream/-/readable-stream-1.1.14.tgz
>   npm info install xtend@4.0.1 into
>   /var/lib/openshift/573d0ed67628e174130000dc/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/cool-ascii-faces/node_modules/stream-spigot
>   npm info install readable-stream@1.1.14 into
>   /var/lib/openshift/573d0ed67628e174130000dc/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/cool-ascii-faces/node_modules/stream-spigot
>   npm info installOne xtend@4.0.1 npm info installOne
>   readable-stream@1.1.14 npm info preinstall xtend@4.0.1 npm info build
>   /var/lib/openshift/573d0ed67628e174130000dc/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/cool-ascii-faces/node_modules/stream-spigot/node_modules/xtend
>   npm info linkStuff xtend@4.0.1 npm info install xtend@4.0.1 npm info
>   postinstall xtend@4.0.1 npm info preinstall readable-stream@1.1.14 npm
>   info trying registry request attempt 1 at 20:55:42 npm http GET
>   https://registry.npmjs.org/core-util-is npm info trying registry
>   request attempt 1 at 20:55:42 npm http GET
>   https://registry.npmjs.org/isarray npm info trying registry request
>   attempt 1 at 20:55:42 npm http GET
>   https://registry.npmjs.org/string_decoder npm info trying registry
>   request attempt 1 at 20:55:42 npm http GET
>   https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits npm http 200
>   https://registry.npmjs.org/core-util-is npm http 200
>   https://registry.npmjs.org/isarray npm http 200
>   https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits npm http 200
>   https://registry.npmjs.org/string_decoder npm info retry fetch attempt
>   1 at 20:55:42 npm info retry fetch attempt 1 at 20:55:42 npm http GET
>   https://registry.npmjs.org/isarray/-/isarray-0.0.1.tgz npm http GET
>   https://registry.npmjs.org/core-util-is/-/core-util-is-1.0.2.tgz npm
>   info retry fetch attempt 1 at 20:55:42 npm info retry fetch attempt 1
>   at 20:55:42 npm http GET
>   https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits/-/inherits-2.0.1.tgz npm http GET
>   https://registry.npmjs.org/string_decoder/-/string_decoder-0.10.31.tgz
>   npm http 200
>   https://registry.npmjs.org/core-util-is/-/core-util-is-1.0.2.tgz npm
>   http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/isarray/-/isarray-0.0.1.tgz npm
>   http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits/-/inherits-2.0.1.tgz npm
>   http 200
>   https://registry.npmjs.org/string_decoder/-/string_decoder-0.10.31.tgz
>   npm info install core-util-is@1.0.2 into
>   /var/lib/openshift/573d0ed67628e174130000dc/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/cool-ascii-faces/node_modules/stream-spigot/node_modules/readable-stream
>   npm info install isarray@0.0.1 into
>   /var/lib/openshift/573d0ed67628e174130000dc/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/cool-ascii-faces/node_modules/stream-spigot/node_modules/readable-stream
>   npm info install inherits@2.0.1 into
>   /var/lib/openshift/573d0ed67628e174130000dc/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/cool-ascii-faces/node_modules/stream-spigot/node_modules/readable-stream
>   npm info install string_decoder@0.10.31 into
>   /var/lib/openshift/573d0ed67628e174130000dc/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/cool-ascii-faces/node_modules/stream-spigot/node_modules/readable-stream
>   npm info installOne core-util-is@1.0.2 npm info installOne
>   isarray@0.0.1 npm info installOne inherits@2.0.1 npm info installOne
>   string_decoder@0.10.31 npm info preinstall isarray@0.0.1 npm info
>   preinstall inherits@2.0.1 npm info build
>   /var/lib/openshift/573d0ed67628e174130000dc/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/cool-ascii-faces/node_modules/stream-spigot/node_modules/readable-stream/node_modules/isarray
>   npm info linkStuff isarray@0.0.1 npm info install isarray@0.0.1 npm
>   info build
>   /var/lib/openshift/573d0ed67628e174130000dc/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/cool-ascii-faces/node_modules/stream-spigot/node_modules/readable-stream/node_modules/inherits
>   npm info linkStuff inherits@2.0.1 npm info install inherits@2.0.1 npm
>   info postinstall isarray@0.0.1 npm info postinstall inherits@2.0.1 npm
>   info preinstall string_decoder@0.10.31 npm info build
>   /var/lib/openshift/573d0ed67628e174130000dc/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/cool-ascii-faces/node_modules/stream-spigot/node_modules/readable-stream/node_modules/string_decoder
>   npm info linkStuff string_decoder@0.10.31 npm info install
>   string_decoder@0.10.31 npm info postinstall string_decoder@0.10.31 npm
>   info preinstall core-util-is@1.0.2 npm info build
>   /var/lib/openshift/573d0ed67628e174130000dc/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/cool-ascii-faces/node_modules/stream-spigot/node_modules/readable-stream/node_modules/core-util-is
>   npm info linkStuff core-util-is@1.0.2 npm info install
>   core-util-is@1.0.2 npm info postinstall core-util-is@1.0.2 npm info
>   build
>   /var/lib/openshift/573d0ed67628e174130000dc/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/cool-ascii-faces/node_modules/stream-spigot/node_modules/readable-stream
>   npm info linkStuff readable-stream@1.1.14 npm info install
>   readable-stream@1.1.14 npm info postinstall readable-stream@1.1.14 npm
>   info build
>   /var/lib/openshift/573d0ed67628e174130000dc/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/cool-ascii-faces/node_modules/stream-spigot
>   npm info linkStuff stream-spigot@3.0.5 npm info install
>   stream-spigot@3.0.5 npm info postinstall stream-spigot@3.0.5 npm info
>   build
>   /var/lib/openshift/573d0ed67628e174130000dc/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/cool-ascii-faces
>   npm info linkStuff cool-ascii-faces@1.3.4 npm info install
>   cool-ascii-faces@1.3.4 npm info postinstall cool-ascii-faces@1.3.4 npm
>   info build
>   /var/lib/openshift/573d0ed67628e174130000dc/app-root/runtime/repo npm
>   info linkStuff node-js-getting-started@0.1.2 npm info install
>   node-js-getting-started@0.1.2 npm info postinstall
>   node-js-getting-started@0.1.2 npm info prepublish
>   node-js-getting-started@0.1.2 director@1.2.8 node_modules/director
>   cool-ascii-faces@1.3.4 node_modules/cool-ascii-faces └──
>   stream-spigot@3.0.5 (xtend@4.0.1, readable-stream@1.1.14) npm info ok
>   Preparing build for deployment Deployment id is ffe6b411 Activating
>   deployment Starting NodeJS cartridge Wed May 18 2016 20:55:44 GMT-0400
>   (EDT): Starting application 'jaybot' ... Waiting for application port
>   (8080) become available ... Application 'jaybot' failed to start (port
>   8080 not available) ------------------------- Git Post-Receive Result:
>   failure Activation status: failure Activation failed for the following
>   gears: 573d0ed67628e174130000dc (Error activating gear: CLIENT_ERROR:
>   Failed to execute: 'control start' for
>   /var/lib/openshift/573d0ed67628e174130000dc/nodejs
>
> ## # ) Deployment completed with status: failure postreceive failed

I'm pretty lost.

Any ideas?

Comment: Assuming that you've installed NodeJS and Express I recommend you 'creating' an application by the following script on: http://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html

Comment: Try checking your disk quota, you can find out more information about how to check how much space you are using here: https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/filesystem.html#disk-space